# Is it correct to say "the baby is lying face down in her arms" in this situation?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, phrase-request

> **[face down/downwards](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/face-down-downwards)**
>
> with the face or front towards the ground
>
> Keith was lying face down on the bed.

### [image]

But what if the face of the baby facing towards the mom's chest & we don't see the baby's face, as the following picture

[image]

Is it correct to say "**the baby is lying face down in her arms**" in this situation?

Or should we say "**the baby is lying with the face facing the mommy's front**"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I think you realise, "face down" is not correct for the situation in that second photo - the mothers face is pointing down, but since she is clearly standing upright the phrase doesn't fit for either person.

I'm struggling to come up with a perfect replacement, but if you want to say that the baby's face is hidden, then "the baby's face is hidden as it snuggles in to its mothers arms" would work.

Comment: Should we say "the baby is lying with the face facing the mommy's front"?

Comment: @Tom  I think we can do better than that - it comes across as very clumsy, and technically the baby isn't really 'lying'. How about: "the baby is facing into its mummy's chest." (I think 'snuggled' is better than 'facing' but not sure how international that is.)

Comment: you mean "her mommy's chest" or "it's mommy's chest"?